Build fail when deploying Next project to Vercel
When attempting to deploy to Vercel I get the following errors:

This is my Layout.tsx file:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { ProviderWrapper } from "@/utilities/providers/ProviderWrapper";
import { NextIntlClientProvider, useMessages } from "next-intl";
import StyledComponentsRegistry from "./registry";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
  locale: string;
}

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Test",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children, locale }: Props) {
  const messages = useMessages();

  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <StyledComponentsRegistry>
          <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale} messages={messages}>
            <ProviderWrapper>{children}</ProviderWrapper>
          </NextIntlClientProvider>
        </StyledComponentsRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

And my .eslintrc.json file:
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "plugins": ["unused-imports", "import"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "warn",
        "import/order": [
          "error",
          {
            "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
            "pathGroups": [
              {
                "pattern": "**",
                "group": "internal",
                "position": "after"
              }
            ],
            "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["builtin"],
            "newlines-between": "always",
            "alphabetize": { "order": "asc" }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

I've attempted to remove the metadata export, leaving only one export in the Layout file. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue.
Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how to address this problem? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I think you can't change the Props of the Layout. It accepts children (required) and params (optional). Params is used for dynamic routes.
Layout Props
Which seems to be a similar problem as this:
Stack Overflow Question
